# I can't get my usb modem to work (Huawei, 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, usb-modem, huawei, usb-modeswitch

I am new to **Ubuntu** - I just installed it yesterday and I have been having some problems.

I would very much like to use my USB Mobile Broadband modem to gain access to the internet so I can do things like download WINE and run steam.I know the Modem is working because I am using right now in Windows 8. But I simply cannot get it to work.I went to the connections manager and had some trouble but to no avail.I also tried to launch the built in **.exe** (which I know doesn't work on Ubuntu.)

I searched for something that is the Ubuntu version of a **.exe** but couldn't find anything.I downloaded WINE on windows and tried to open it in Ubuntu but still couldn't get it right. I think that if I could get my internet to work I could download it from the Software centre and then hopefully have more success. I could also access the internet to search for solutions without having to restart my computer.I have searched for some time now for something to do but came up with nothing so if there is another thread that deals with the problem sorry.

I have the latest **Ubuntu** (14.04 LTS). The modem is [by] Huawei, and the service provider is 8ta. *Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Start by reading: http://askubuntu.com/questions/487340/huawei-e353-s-6-bsnl-3g-14-4mbps-works-in-ubuntu-13-04-but-not-in-ubuntu-14-04 Report back on the USB ID for the device, etc.

Comment: @david6 As far as I can tell the ID is ASMT 2105,exactly what other data do you need

Comment: Start with output from **`lsusb`**, that is added when the device is attached. eg. **12d1:1506** (or similar), which is the brand/model of device. *Also see if this changes, after a few seconds, with the device attached.*